# Convert LinkedList<String[]> to String[][]

Tags: java, linked-list

If I have a linked list of String[], how can I convert it into String[][].

Comment: `for` loops. How do they work?

Comment: LinkedList implements Collection.toArray()

Comment: Downvoting because if you had consulted the javadocs, the answer would have been obvious.  Here, I googled it for you too: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Comments seem a bit harsh given that `Collection.toArray()/toArray(T[])` with arrays of arrays isn't that obvious (and doesn't require use of `for` loops). / I'd stick with `List<List<String>>` or List<SomethingContainingAListOfStringsAsAnImplementationDetail>`.

Comment: this question is not as bad as it seems, upvoted :)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - My comment was meant to be funny, not a definitive solution. That being said ... without any knowledge of core classes and without having ever read any javadoc one would assume you'd at least think of iteration when confronted with a list of things and perhaps ask if there was something better.

Comment: @BrianRoach: Perhaps you've heard of the war against fun?  Sarcastic comments don't really help people.

Comment: @BrianRoach I actually read the JavaDocs and was trying to use .toArray but I didn't know the correct syntax and I was very close to the deadline. I have no problem admitting my question seems damn lazy, but it worked and I got the correct answer and manage to finish in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this:

```
LinkedList<String[]> list = new LinkedList<String[]>();
// add elements
String[][] myArray = list.toArray(new String[][] {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Java lists define a [toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method you can call. In the future checking with the JavaDoc is a great place to start.

Answer (score -2):

You would use:

```
LinkedList<String[]> myLinkedList = new LinkedList<String[]>();
// add elements or whatever
String[][] myArray = null;
myArray = myLinkedList.toArray(myArray);
```

This question shows very poor research effort.  This is a library class, and the method you need is documented in the javadocs online.  A simple google search would have found it.

[LinkedList Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Comment: `String[][] myArray = myLinkedList.toArray(new String[0][]);` or is it `String[][] myArray = myLinkedList.toArray(new String[][0]);`.

Comment: I think the first one is right.  I however am going to cheat.  see edit.

Comment: @Wug: i guess it is because of `myArray` variable (i didn't downvote though)

Comment: That's what I thought, but there's nothing wrong with doing it this way. The argument is ignored, it's only used to trick Java's syntax into being able to return a value of the correct type.  There is fundamentally no difference in passing a null variable already declared and passing the newly allocated empty string array, except it saves a useless allocation and is easier to maintain (if you change the type of the array, the toArray argument doesn't need to be changed as well)

Comment: I'm sure others do it this way.  I was inspired by the C statement `int * i = malloc(sizeof(*i));`, which is actually considered something of a protip.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that passing a null means the type information isn't passed in correctly.  You'd be better off doing it Tom's way.

Comment: Yup, this will give an NPE (or something). If it was just a matter of static type information, this could be given as generic arguments to the method. But it's arrays, so it's broken.

Comment: Ah, I spose it figures it out with reflection or something.